# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Network error: apollo_cache_inmemory_1.readQueryFromStore is not a function aws appsync nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

I am trying to call an Graphql Query for my AWS AppSync app through nodejs. The error I am encountering is

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Network error:
>   apollo_cache_inmemory_1.readQueryFromStore

This is my index.js code

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var config = {
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: <ACCESS_KEY_ID>,
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: <SECRET_KEY>,
HOST: '<HOST_URL>',
REGION: 'us-west-2',
PATH: '/graphql',
ENDPOINT: '<AWS_APPSYNC_ENDPOINT>',
};

config.ENDPOINT = "https://" + config.HOST + config.PATH;
exports.default = config;

global.localStorage = {
    store: {},
    getItem: function (key) {
        return this.store[key]
    },
    setItem: function (key, value) {
        this.store[key] = value
    },
    removeItem: function (key) {
        delete this.store[key]
    }
};

require('es6-promise').polyfill();
require('isomorphic-fetch');

// Require AppSync module
const AUTH_TYPE = "AWS_IAM";
const AWSAppSyncClient = require('aws-appsync').default;

const url = config.ENDPOINT;
const region = config.REGION;
const type = AUTH_TYPE.AWS_IAM;

// If you want to use API key-based auth
const apiKey = 'xxxxxxxxx';
// If you want to use a jwtToken from Amazon Cognito identity:
const jwtToken = 'xxxxxxxx';

// If you want to use AWS...
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({
    region: config.REGION,
    credentials: new AWS.Credentials({
        accessKeyId: config.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: config.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    })
});
const credentials = AWS.config.credentials;

// Import gql helper and craft a GraphQL query
const gql = require('graphql-tag');
const query = gql(`
    query {
        getSample {
            mobileNumber
        }
    }
`);

// Set up Apollo client
const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
    url: url,
    region: region,
    auth: {
        type: type,
        credentials: credentials,
    }
});

client.hydrated().then(function a(client) {
    client.query({query: query});
    client.query({ query: query, fetchPolicy: 'network-only'}).then(function(data) {
        console.log("data: " + queryResult);
    })
});
```

The complete stacktrace is the following:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Network error:
>   apollo_cache_inmemory_1.readQueryFromStore is not a function
>       at new ApolloError (/Users/kanhaiagarwal/appsync1/node_modules/aws-appsync/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:124:32)
>       at /Users/kanhaiagarwal/appsync1/node_modules/aws-appsync/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1248:45
>       at /Users/kanhaiagarwal/appsync1/node_modules/aws-appsync/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1680:21
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at /Users/kanhaiagarwal/appsync1/node_modules/aws-appsync/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1679:22
>       at Map.forEach ()
>       at QueryManager.broadcastQueries (/Users/kanhaiagarwal/appsync1/node_modules/aws-appsync/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1672:26)
>       at /Users/kanhaiagarwal/appsync1/node_modules/aws-appsync/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1175:35
>       at  (node:23377) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing
>   inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a
>   promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>   (node:23377) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are
>   not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit
>   code.

Can someone suggest a solution for this?

Comment: Nobody there with the knowledge about aws lambda with nodejs and appsync?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, running in Node.js. Did you get anywhere toward getting it working?

Comment: I've created an [issue in GitHub](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js/issues/276). It looks like the code I'm using is correct as it works in a browser. It's just Node.js that's the problem.

Comment: Still did not get any solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by not providing a `window` object that the aws-appsync package relies on for some global objects. This is not present in the Node.js environment and adding the following at the start of your script should make it work:

```
global.window = global.window || {
    setTimeout: setTimeout,
    clearTimeout: clearTimeout,
    WebSocket: global.WebSocket,
    ArrayBuffer: global.ArrayBuffer,
    addEventListener: function () { },
    navigator: { onLine: true }
};
```

Here's the GitHub issue where the answer was proposed:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js/issues/276#issuecomment-432983691